# What ES6 can Node js 6 use now?

Tags: node.js

I see that, according to the Node js website,

> Node.js now supports 93% of ES6 language features

I couldnt find a link to this list and wondered if one exists?

If there is no definative supported ES6 list then I would also like to know if Node 6 Can use `import` statements without a transpiler?

Comment: Ok, google :) https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't use `import` at the moment and don't expect it any time soon.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6526

> ES6 modules fall into the missing 7%. It's still not clear how or even if Node will support these yet.

The V8 feature/bug for modules is [also open](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1569). The module syntax/parser is defined in ECMAScript 2015. The [loader](https://github.com/whatwg/loader) isn't, which Google is using for it's implementation.

http://node.green/ has detailed Node.js support for ES6 features both protected and unprotected by `--harmony`. Modules aren't in the table yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the "Servers/Runtimes" column set of [ES 6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Imports can not be currently used without a transpiler. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53) which you can track. The node team plans to integrate it once V8 supports it natively. It's [implementation status](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5365692190687232) is "In development" as per official Web Platform Features status page.